# Regex replace if caption does not contain character in PHP

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm finishing BBCode support for my CMS. I'm using regex to convert the BBCode to html and vice versa. But yet, i have a little problem with security. I have for example regular expression:

```
~\[img=(.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png))\|(.*?)\[/img\]~s
```

to determinate for example this

```
[img=somewhere.com\image\08-09-2014\cat.png|This is a cat[/img]
```

But it also works on strings like this, but that I really don't want to.

```
[img=somewhere.com" onclick="someBadJSCode()" src="\image\08-09-2014\cat.png|This is a cat[/img]
```

I thought that this edit to regex will help:

```
~\[img=([^"]+.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png))\|(.*?)\[/img\]~s
```

But it actually didn't, dunno why. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just sanitize all `"` characters from all possible attribute inputs?

Comment: @sjagr I can't replace `"` in whole message, I use them for other reasons. I just need to replace them in the first caption group in img and link codes. Any ideas?

Comment: `~\[img=([^"'|]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png))\|(.*?)\[/img\]~s` perhaps. But note that it is always possible to put javascript code in the text part.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, that's it. Thank you (for the regex and for the text part reminder)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Casimir et Hippolyte, i got the regex, that works for the url, alt and class part without any JS danger.

Converts this:

```
[img=somewhere.com/img.jpg|left]cat[/img]
```

to this:

```
<img src="somewhere.com/img.jpg" class="left" alt="cat" >
```

Pattern for preg_replace method (1. parameter)

```
~\[img=([^"']+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png))\|([^"']+)\]([^"']+)\[/img\]~s
```

Replacement for preg_replace method (2. parameter)

```
'<img src="$1" class="'.$this->GetElementClass('img').'  $2" alt="$3" >'
```

Comment: Note that adding `|` in the character class `[^|"']` avoids many backtracking since the greedy quantifier stops before the literal `|`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't quite understand your comment, can you make it more simple please?

Comment: Quantifiers (`*`, `+`, `?`) are by default greedy, that means they takes all possible characters. After, these quantifiers must give characters back until the next subpattern succeeds. In the present case, if you write `[^"']+\.jpg\|`, `[^"']+` will match all characters until the next quote (simple or double) or the end of the string, and after it must give back (one character at a time) until `\.jpg\|` succeeds. If you write `[^|"']+\.jpg\|`, you limit this mechanism to 4 characters only(the length of ".jpg").